# How to call parent navigator from nested navigator component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am getting undefined is not object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation') 
when i call it inside nested component

I tried to use withNavigation for nested navigator and component also.

root navigator in separated

```
const stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: TabNav
    },
    ProductsList:{
        screen: ProductsList
    };

const MainNavigation = createAppContainer(stackNavigator);

export default MainNavigation;
```

nested navigator separated

```
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home:{
        screen: Home,   
    },
    Whislist: WishList,
    Cart: Cart,
    Account: MyAccount
});

export default TabNav;
```

and this how to implement my use root navigator in App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MainNavigation/>
  );
};

export default App;
```

this my home component, featured, offers and categories component are working fine

```
class Home extends Component {
 product =[];
 offers=[]
 category=[]


 nav() {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("ProductsList");
 };
 state = {
  products: this.products,
  offers: this.offer,
  categories: this.category
 };
 render() {
  return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView>
     <FeaturedProducts items={this.state.products}></FeaturedProducts>
     <Offers offers={this.state.offers}></Offers>
     <Categories nav={this.nav} categories={this.state.categories}> </Categories>
    </ScrollView>
   </View>
  );
 };
};
export default Home;
```

react: "16.8.6",
react-native: "0.60.4",
react-navigation: "^3.11.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide the full code, I don't know what you mean with nested component. I imagine you have a situation like:

```
<View>
   <NestedComponent/> //Inside this component you are trying to do this.props.navigation 
</View>
```

You have to either use withNavigation or pass the navigation props to the component:

```
<NestedComponent navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

Then you can call `this.props.navigation` inside your nested component.

EDIT.

Looks like you didn't bind you function to the component `this`. You have to either use an arrow function doing:

```
nav=()=>{
this.props.navigation.navigate("ProductsList")
}
```

or binding the function in your constructor doing:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.nav = this.nav.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Actually no, when i run the code it s go directly to home component, when i use your approach, it ask me to modify my code to same code i posted

Comment: Can you post some more code? Here I can only see the navigation structure, without seeing where you are calling `this.props.navigation `

Comment: Does your nav function have access to `this`? Try adding in your constructor   `this.nav = this.nav.bind(this);`